# How to find real lexeme start position in source document from tsvector?

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, tsvector

A sample document and `tsvector` out of it:

```sql
select
    *
from
    unnest(to_tsvector('english', 'something wide this more wider and wider social-economy wide somethings'))
```

| lexeme | positions |
| --- | --- |
| economi | 10 |
| social | 9 |
| social-economi | 8 |
| someth | 1,12 |
| wide | 2,11 |
| wider | 5,7 |

How do I interpret these positions on a client?
The [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-textsearch.html#DATATYPE-TSVECTOR) says that:

> A position ***normally*** indicates the source **word's** location in the document.

*(emphasis is mine)*

This 'normally' part is what confuses me.

A location in my understanding is a starting **symbol** index in a document. But here it seems to be just a **lexeme's** order index, not symbol index or even word order index.

I need to highlight the lexemes in a source document just like they are processed by Postgres (without `ts_headline`). But using the sample above word `wide` should be found at **locations** `2` and `11`. However, since Postgres uses stemming, stop-word dictionaries, etc. the **real** word locations are different.

So how do I 'map' lexeme's positions to source document to highlight them? On a client. I need Postgres to just return the data it uses internally and interpret it somehow.

Basically, in the end I need to see something like this:

> **something** **wide** this more **wider** and **wider** **social**-**economy** **wide** **somethings**

My first approach was to split the source document by whitespaces in tokens on a client, retrieve the `tsvector`, extract lexemes and compare each token with a lexeme using something like a `string.StartsWith` (currently on `C#`). But the problem is that some lexemes are a bit different from the source document's words. Note the '*econom**i***' lexeme vs '*econom**y***' token in source document. Also in a real project there are some extra synonyms used and so using `string.StartsWith` won't work.

That's why I needed real **symbol** positions.
Is it possible to get them somehow?

###### UPDATE_01

Here is a sample of how I tried to split the source on a client to map locations (using `C#`):

```cs
var source = "something wide this more wider and wider social-economy wide somethings";
source
    .Split(new[] { ' ', '-' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries | StringSplitOptions.TrimEntries)
    .Select((w, i) => new
    {
        Word = w,
        Pos = i + 1,
    })
    .OrderBy(w => w.Word)
;
```

| lexeme | positions |
| --- | --- |
| and | 6 |
| economy | 9 |
| more | 4 |
| social | 8 |
| something | 1 |
| somethings | 11 |
| this | 3 |
| wide | 2 |
| wide | 10 |
| wider | 5 |
| wider | 7 |

Some of them do match, others mostly not.

Comment: Your assumption is wrong: look at position 3 and 4: the stop words are removed but their position are kept. Instead, focus on the hyphenated word that takes 3 positions by itself! You splitting approach might work if you split by space and hyphen.

Comment: @JGH not sure what you mean.  I've added a sample of source splitting. Could you please point me where I'm wrong?

Comment: @KasbolatKumakhov Not sure what you exactly need, try this query in Postgres

`SELECT word, ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS word_row_number
FROM ( SELECT unnest(string_to_array('something wide this more wider and wider social-economy wide somethings', ' ')) AS word) s
  order by word;`

Query2
`WITH provided_text AS (
SELECT unnest(string_to_array(regexp_replace('something wide this more wider and wider social-economy wide somethings', E'[-]', ' ', 'g'), ' ')) AS text) 
SELECT text, ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS word_row_number FROM provided_text order by text;`

Comment: @SenthilPNathan, thanks, but that's not it. Commented on your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see Postgres considering social-economi(y) as one word first and providing the position as 8 and then social as 9 and economi 10 (repeating it as a different word and doing plus 1) and the remaining words have +1 added to it followed by economi(y).
As @KasbolatKumakhov said we can use \W regex pattern to replace all non word characters with spaces and use that.

```
SELECT *
FROM unnest(to_tsvector('english',
             regexp_replace('something;wide {}{}{ this.more wider and\wider social-economy wide/somethings
               wide;somethings wide&somethings wide|somethings wide+somethings wide"somethings wide.somethings 
               wide=somethings wide#somethings wide@somethings wide*somethings
               wide~somethings wide$somethings wide:somethings wideËsomethings wide wideËsomethings',
                            E'\\W', ' ', 'g')));
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is the same as in my `UPDATE_01` and is not equals to what `to_tsvector` gives. Just compare the positions. I need to find words in source document by lexeme position in `tsvector`. That's the main goal.

Comment: @KasbolatKumakhov
Please can you let me know the exact output for the input provided so I can work on it and provide the script

Comment: I'm afraid you misunderstood the question. It's the output that is the problem. The main goal is to map lexemes positions to source document. In other words, which word from the **source** document a lexeme position is pointing to? For example, take a look at a positions table in the first post. A `social` lexeme has a position `9` in `tsvector`. Which word from the **source** document is located at position `9`? If using a simple whitespace-hyphen split method it will be `economy`, not `social`. And `economy` itself is at position `10` in `tsvector`. That's the problem.

Comment: @KasbolatKumakhov, I see Postgres considering social-economi(y) as one word first and providing the position as 8 and then social as 9 and economi 10 (repeating it as a different word and doing plus 1) and the remaining words have +1 added to it followed by economi(y). 
what if we replace hyphens - not sure it sorts your query but correct positions reflect select * from unnest(to_tsvector('english', regexp_replace('something wide this more wider and wider social-economy wide somethings', E'[-]', ' ', 'g')))

Check this out https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/2437094.FICmWb5XyZ@bregalad

Comment: well, I guess that's a reasonable workaround. To make it full I just need a list for word separators, like 'space', 'hyphen', etc. which could be used to preprocess documents and convert them to a single 'normalized' form before using with `to_tsvector`. Haven't found it from the docs, but if you edit your post with this new idea, I could mark it as resolved.

Comment: On a second thought, one could simply use `\W` regex pattern to replace all non word characters with spaces and use that. But not sure if it's going to be enough in common scenarios.

Comment: Yes that seems to be working I also tried placing a diacritic mark above any character

`SELECT *
FROM unnest(to_tsvector('english',
             regexp_replace('something;wide {}{}{ this.more wider and\wider social-economy wide/somethings
      wide;somethings wide&somethings wide|somethings wide+somethings wide"somethings wide.somethings 
      wide=somethings wide#somethings wide@somethings wide*somethings
      wide~somethings wide$somethings wide:somethings wideËsomethings wide wideËsomethings',
                            E'\\W', ' ', 'g')));
`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255407/discussion-between-senthil-p-nathan-and-kasbolat-kumakhov).